# image within link wont center align

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, alignment, bootstrap-carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel in my angular app. I added on a tags to the images so that when someone clicks an image it redirects to a particular page. I can't get the image to align to the center of the window (except if I alter the padding, which will cause issues if the window is minimized at all. Also, since I added the a tag, I also can't seem to set the background color of the div containing the image (it was working fine before I added the link).I'll post my HTML and CSS code. Will appreciate any help, thanks!

```
<ngb-carousel [showNavigationArrows]="true" 
[showNavigationIndicators]="true"
interval="12000"
[keyboard]="true"
[pauseOnHover]="true"
[wrap]="true"
[activeId]="'secondSlide'"
 [interval]="3000" [pauseOnHover]="pauseOnHover" (slide)="onSlide($event)">
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/blog/1">
      <img src="../../assets/img/actual.png" alt="Angular Carousel 1"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Title Goes Here</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/blog/2">
      <img src="../../assets/img/image0.jpeg" alt="Angular Carousel 2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Title Goes Here</h3>
      <p>Consectetur tortor volutpat pretium.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

```
a.nav-link {
  background-color: #361833 !important;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;

}

a {
  background-color: #361833 !important;

}
 
 div {
   background-color: #361833 !important;
   color: white;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: orpheuspro, serif;
   font-style: normal; 
   font-weight: 600 !important;
   /* margin-left: auto !important;
   margin-right: auto !important;
    */
}  

img {
  background-color: #361833 !important;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 30px ;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 650px;
  height: 450px;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
}



h3 {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

p {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}


ol {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

li {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

#ngb-slide-4 {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}


.carousel-caption {
  background-color:transparent !important;
}

.picsum-img-wrapper {
  background-color: #361833 !important;
  /* justify-content: center !important;
  text-align: center !important; */

  /* margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  padding-right: 300px; */
}

div.carousel-inner {
  background-color: #361833 !important;
}
```

I tried setting margin left and right to auto but no change. Aligning the image/ div containing the image also didnt seem to work.

Comment: when u in developer tools, what is the css of the offending component?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka sorry what does that mean exactly?

Comment: press F12 when you see the page in question in the browser. Choose INSPECT (usually all the way to the top left). move your mouse until you are on the html element that is not behaving properly, and left click. On the right side of the window will open a tab with the elem CSS.